Regression Modelling using lme4 in R
I have GPS collar data on a species of desert gazelle throughout different seasons and want to model the effect of seasonal changes in weather patterns on their movement patterns (e.g. daily distance moved) using the lme4 package in R.
There are different amounts of data for each individual, as some of them died early. For example, one individual could have data for 90 days whereas another has data for 450 days. The  range is 11 to 459 days. The collars take a GPS fix every hour, so for every day there are max 24 locations, but sometimes the collar can malfunction and there could be a few missing. I also have temperature data from the collars for each GPS location and each time.
I calculated the max, min, and mean temperature for each day and the average distance moved for each day for each individual. I would like to model the effect of temperature on the daily movement patterns of the animals using a regression model in lme4
#The structure of my data looks like this:
str(data)
# tibble [16,641 × 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ COLLARID  : chr [1:16641] "IRI2016-4471" "IRI2016-4471" ...
# $ SEX       : chr [1:16641] "Male" "Male" "Male" "Male" ...
# $ ZONE      : chr [1:16641] "H" "H" "H" "H" ...
# $ DATE      : Date[1:16641], format: "2023-03-11" ...
# $ TEMP.MAX  : num [1:16641] 29.7 25.2 26.9 29.4 25.4 32.2 26.1 18.8 ...
# $ TEMP.MIN  : num [1:16641] 10 13 16.4 13 16.5 12.9 15.3 11.2 15.7 ...
# $ TEMP.MEAN : num [1:16641] 22.7 19.5 21.6 24.3 20.7 ...
# $ TOTAL_DIST: num [1:16641] 6408 10999 11604 10785 11781 ...

# I used the following code to run a mixed effects model on the data, with the max temp as a fixed effect and collar ID (i.e., the individual animal) as a random effect:

model1 <- lmer(TOTAL_DIST ~ TEMP.MAX + (1 | COLLARID), data = dat.sg)

# Summary for the model:

summary(model1)

#Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#Formula: TOTAL_DIST ~ TEMP.MAX + (1 | COLLARID)
#   Data: dat.sg
#
#REML criterion at convergence: 338556
#
#Scaled residuals: 
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-2.3846 -0.6187 -0.1946  0.3689 17.0222 
#
#Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
# COLLARID (Intercept)  6471327 2544    
# Residual             39528228 6287    
#Number of obs: 16641, groups:  COLLARID, 86
#
#Fixed effects:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value
#(Intercept) 9268.979    367.720  25.207
#TEMP.MAX      25.951      6.788   3.823
#
#Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#         (Intr)
#TEMP.MAX -0.625

The residuals look really big.. Would the above be the correct way to model the effect of temperature changes throughout seasons on the movement patterns of the gazelle?

I'm a bit confused by the structure of your data. Are both datasets time series? What are the values under each date representing? You are just looking to estimate the effect of time on each DV (daily distance moved and monthly home range sizes)?

This should not be modeled like a lme model, and that makes it difficult to say hoe to model it as a lme model. Sure, you could convert your data to a variable like daily activity/movement and fit it with a linear model being dependent on daily temperature with random effects like time, location and gazelle. But you may have more complex patterns, there could be sporadic movements triggered by weather changes (either getting colder or getting warmer), and there is probably a lot of auto-correlation making inference tricky.

With this type of data I would start with exploring the data to come up with a model first. I would love to first see the spatial movement pattern in a 2D map and visualize the motions along with colour coding for different ways of representing the temperature (seasonal temperature, variations from the mean, etc. ).


I would like to model the effect of temperature on the daily movement patterns of the animals using a regression model in lme4

The model:
TOTAL_DIST ~ TEMP.MAX + (1 | COLLARID)

Has the following features:
- TEMP.MAX:  Fixed effect for the maximum daily temperature:
- (1 | COLLARID). Random intercept for subject
The random intercepts are fitted because we expect there to be non-independence of observation within each subject.
The intercept estimate for the model is 9268.979 units which tells you that when TEMP.MAX is zero, the estimated mean value of TOTAL_DIST when the predictor TEMP.MAX is zero, is 9268.979 units.
The coefficient estimate for TEMP.MAX is 25.951, indicating that as the maximum temperature increases by 1 degree, the total distance moved increases by an average of 25.951 units. Note that this is a linear trend/slope. I would be quite surprised the association between TEMP.MAX and TOTAL_DISTis linear over the whole range of TEMP.MAX. Did you plot them against each other ? That will immediately show that the association is linear or not. If it is nonlinear then you can add nonlinear terms, or regression splines for TEMP.MAX
